# Adding Widgets to Masonry Layouts Correctly - jQuery &&|| PHP

Tags: jquery

I tried incrementally adding in my widget area to the masonry layout (PHP below) it appears but I cannot get it included into the masonry like the other blocks.

```
        $counts = 0 ;
        $addin = get_sidebar('masonry'); 

        foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); $counts++; ?>
                <div class="box">
                <?php  if($count == 9) {echo $addin;} else {?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <h2><?php the_title(); echo $counts; // just to see ?></h2>
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                }?>
                <?php the_content();?></a>
                </div><?php } endforeach; ?>
```

I also tried this jQuery but it broke my masonry:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.arrange').masonry({
       itemSelector: '.box',
       isFitWidth: true,
    });
 $('#addinWidget').click(function(){
        var $container = $('#mas-widget');
        var addinWidget = $('<div class="element"><?php get_sidebar('masonry');?></div>');
        addinWidget.insertAfter($container.find('.element').eq(3));
        $container.masonry('reload');
    });
```

Could someone lead me in the right direction to place my widgets correctly inside the masonry layout AT/NEXT TO or IN FRONT OF a specified block number?

Comment: Anybody have any advice at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Here's the get_posts method to add a widget (or any content into a masonry layout at the "$counts" number you define)

```
<div class="arrange">
        <?php 
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'  => 10000,
            'offset'          => 5,
            'orderby'         => 'post_date',
            'order'           => 'DESC',
            'exclude'         => 'none',
            // 'post_type'       => array('post', 'page', 'video_type', 'review_type' ),
            'post_status'     => 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => true 
            ); 

        $posts = get_posts($args);
        $counts = 0 ;
        foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); $counts++; 
            get_sidebar('corner-box');?>
                <div class="box"> 
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); echo $counts; // to see your box number ?></h2>
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {the_post_thumbnail('masonry');} 
                        the_content();?>
                    </a>
                </div><?php if($counts == 9) { get_sidebar('masonry');}
                endforeach; ?>

    </div> <!-- end masonry -->
```